# WooCommerce display columns on mobile

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, multiple-columns

How do I make woocommerce display 3 or 4 columns on mobile? My shop page only shows 1 column on mobile.

Comment: make shop page column width in percentage

Comment: Alright, thank you.

Comment: Do you got it working?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Show in default resolution screen*/
#container2 {
width: 960px;
position: relative;
margin:0 auto;
line-height: 1.4em;
}

/* If in mobile screen with maximum width 479px. The iPhone screen resolution is 320x480 px (except iPhone4, 640x960) */    
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px){
    #container2 { width: 90%; }
}
```

Set CSS for mobile device in percentage